# Could not transfer artifact HTTPS Required

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Tengo un problema al ejecutar mi proyecto de spring boot desde netbeans; el proyecto funciona si lo ejecuto desde [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) pero al abrirlo desde [netbeans-8.2](/questions/tagged/netbeans-8.2) no funciona y arroja errores

```js
Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.1: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:pom:1.2.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

Comment: * Comprueba que tu netbeans tiene el repository y su archivo de settings.xml(Donde descarga las dependencias) bien configurado
* Después en netbeans actualiza el proyecto maven forzándolo.

Answer (score 1):

Como veras en tu mensaje de error dice 501 (que es un codigo de error HTTP), y despues el mensaje HTTPS Required, diciendo que necesitas usar HTTPS.

Esto es porque a partir del [15 de enero de 2020](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334) para conectarse a maven central se debe conectar mediante https en vez de http remplazando las referencias que tengas

Remplaza http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ con https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Remplaza http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ con https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

y si por alguna razon no pudieras usar https puedes seguir usando http pero deberas conectarte a http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/

El primer lugar donde tienes que cambiar eso si no lo has hecho es en `.m2/settings.xml` que generalmente esta en tu carpeta de usuario